# Need assistance in Pine script to stop a strategy from opening deals in specific time period of the day

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

Need assistance in Pine script to stop a strategy from opening deals in specific time period of the day, Like no deals between 00:00 and 03:00 AM.

any suggestions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the hour built-in variable
hour is based on the charted broker headquarter timezone

```
if hour > 3
    // strategy.entry(...)
```